# Writing object with Spring Vault returns Status 400 : no data provided

Tags: java, spring-vault

I am investigating how I can use Vault 0.11.1 and Spring Vault 2.0.2.RELEASE. I have set up a dev Vault:

```
vault server -dev
```

and added some data

```
vault kv put secret/certs/jan cert=ABCD
```

which I can read with Spring Vault

```
      @Autowired
      private VaultOperations operations;

            String path = "secret/data/certs/jan";
            System.out.println(operations.read(path).getData());
```

note that, curiously, I have to insert "data/" in the path to find it again.

deleting the data works fine too:

```
            operations.delete(path);
```

but writing data with

```
            Secret secret = new Secret("ABCD");
            operations.write(path, secret);
```

fails with

```
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 400 secret/data/certs/jan: no data provided
```

Secret is a simple bean:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Secret {
    String cert;
}
```

and the jason conversion seems to go fine:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [Secret(cert=ABCD)] using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@add0edd]
```

Simply trying to write a String

```
            operations.write(path, "foo=bar");
```

also fails:

```
Status 400 secret/data/certs/jan: failed to parse JSON input: invalid character 'o' in literal false (expecting 'a')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you're using Vault's versioned Key-Value backend. New instances of Vault 0.10 and newer mount the versioned backend by default at `secret/` which requires you to use a specific API.

There are subtle API differences between the unversioned (v1) and versioned (v2) Key Value backend, that add additional elements to the context path and the actual JSON payload.

Example for Key-Value backend v1:

```
POST /v1/secret/certs/jan

{"key":"value"}
```

Example for Key-Value backend v2:

```
POST /v1/secret/data/certs/jan

{"data":{"key":"value"}}
```

For using Spring Vault, this means that you need to upgrade to version 2.1.0 and use the `VaultKeyValueOperations` API:

```java
VaultKeyValueOperations keyValue = vaultOperations.opsForKeyValue("secret", KeyValueBackend.versioned());
keyValue.put("certs/jan", secret);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `operations.opsForKeyValue("secret", KeyValueBackend.unversioned()).put("certs/jan", secret)` gets 404 Not Found and `operations.opsForKeyValue("secret", KeyValueBackend.unversioned()).put("data/certs/jan", secret);` gets `VaultException: Status 400 Bad Request: no data provided`

Comment: Make sure to use the proper version flag. `KeyValueBackend.unversioned()` for key-value v1 (unversioned) and `KeyValueBackend.versioned()` for key-value v2 (versioned).

Comment: `operations.opsForKeyValue("secret", KeyValueBackend.versioned()).put("certs/jan", secret);` works! Thank you.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Adding 'data' resolved it. Thanks

Comment: I tried {"data":{"key":"value"}} = > this is replacing everything in vault. Any way I can just append my new key:value rather than replacing everything with it ?

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari the path points to a single secret and the data is the content of the secret. If you want to persist the previous content first read, then append to the json, and last write updated secret. You can also have multiple secrets in vault to avoid this, and use different secret path for each of them.